# Ошибка в Intellij Idea 14

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NAISSANCE"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at tourdefrance$tdf.parceteamline(tourdefrance.java:152)
at tourdefrance$tdf.createteams(tourdefrance.java:209)
at tourdefrance$tdf.main(tourdefrance.java:224)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Выдает вот такие страшные вещи, которые мне, как совсем-совсем начинающему программисту, ни о чем не говорят. Поиск в гугле выдал сайты на французском языке - видимо, из-за слова `NAISSANCE`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class tourdefrance {
    public static class Racer {
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private String nat;
        private int data;
        private int number;

        public void setname(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setsurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        public void setnat(String nat) {
            this.nat = nat;
        }

        public void setdata(int data) {
            if (data > 1900) {
                this.data = data;
            }
        }

        public void setnumber(int number) {
            if (number > 0) {
                this.number = number;
            }
        }

        public String getname() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getsurname() {
            return this.surname;
        }

        public String getnat() {
            return this.nat;
        }

        public int getdata() {
            return this.data;
        }

        public int getnumber() {
            return this.number;
        }

        public int age(int year) {
            return year - this.data;
        }
    }
//класс Гонщика
    public static class Team {
        private String name;
        ArrayList<Racer> racers;

        public void newteam(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            racers = new ArrayList<Racer>();
        }

        public void insert(Racer racer) {
            this.racers.add(racer);
        }

        public void setname(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getname() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public int numofr() {
            return racers.size();
        }

        public Racer getracer(int i) {
            if (i > -1) {
                return racers.get(i);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public int totalage(int year) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < racers.size(); i++) {
                sum += racers.get(i).age(year);
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
    //класс Команды
        public static class Teamlist {
            ArrayList<Team> teamlist;

            public void insert(Team team) {
                this.teamlist.add(team);
            }

            public void newteamlist() {
                this.teamlist = new ArrayList<Team>();
            }

            public Team getteam(String name) {
                Team team1 = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < this.teamlist.size(); i++) {
                    if (this.teamlist.get(i).name == name) {
                        team1 = this.teamlist.get(i);
                    }
                }
                return team1;
            }

            public int numoft() {
                return this.teamlist.size();
            }

            public Team getteam(int i) {
                if (i > -1) {
                    return this.teamlist.get(i);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    //класс Списка команд
        public static class tdf{
            public static void parceteamline(String line, Teamlist teamlist1) {
                String[] elem = line.split("\t");
                String nat = elem[0];
                String surname = elem[1];
                String name = elem[2];
                int data = Integer.parseInt(elem[3]);
                int number = Integer.parseInt(elem[4]);
                String teamname = elem[5];

                boolean exist = false;
                int x;
                x = teamlist1.numoft();
                int k=0;
                for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
                    if(teamlist1.getteam(i).name==teamname){
                        k=i;
                        exist=true;
                    }
                }
                Racer racer1 = new Racer();

                racer1.setname(name);
                racer1.setsurname(surname);
                racer1.setnat(nat);
                racer1.setdata(data);
                racer1.setnumber(number);

                if(exist==true){
                    teamlist1.getteam(k).insert(racer1);
                }else{
                    Team team1 = new Team();
                    team1.newteam(teamname);
                    team1.insert(racer1);
                    teamlist1.insert(team1);
                }

            }
//Обработка строки
            public static boolean createteams(String fileName, Teamlist teamlist)throws IOException {
                FileInputStream inputFileStream;
                InputStreamReader inputFileReader = null;
                try {

                    inputFileStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

                    inputFileReader = new InputStreamReader(inputFileStream, "UTF-8");
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);

                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputFileReader);

                String line;
                try{
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        parceteamline(line, teamlist);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException ex){
                    return false;
                }
            }
//Обработка документа, использующая Обработку строки
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                final int currentYear = 2014;
                final String teamsFileName = "tdf_teams.txt";

                Teamlist t = new Teamlist();
                t.newteamlist();
                boolean res = createteams(teamsFileName, t);
                if (!res) {
                    System.out.println("Произошла ошибка с чтением списка команд");
                }
                else {
                for(int i=0;i<t.numoft();i++){
                    System.out.println(t.getteam(i).name);
                }
                }
            }
//Главный метод
        }
    //класс Обработки
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всему виной вот эти строки:

```
int data = Integer.parseInt(elem[3]);
int number = Integer.parseInt(elem[4])
```

Используйте отладчик, чтобы прояснить ситуацию. Остановите программу на этих строках и проверьте значение переменных `elem[3]` и `elem[4]`. Почти наверняка там будут не целые числа в виде символов, а какой-то другой текст.

**Обновление**

Вначале каждой строки оглавления поставьте знак '#', например.
Затем в цикле while организуйте проверку:
если символ '#' первый в строке, то пропустить эту строку. Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
while(...){
if (line[0]=='#')
    continue;
parceteamline(line, teamlist);
}
```

Comment: Кажется, разобрался. Проблема в том, что в читаемом файле 1 строчка - оглавление, а потом уже идут нужные мне данные. Не подскажете, что можно использовать, чтобы заставить его читать со второй строки?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @redwolf, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).